# Как сделать апгрейд Composer-а, установленного глобально, до версии 2

Tags: ubuntu, composer

На Ubuntu 20.04 установлен компоузер первой версии. При установке Yii-2 предлагается обновить компоузер до версии 2.На команду sudo apt full-upgrade composer и аналогичные получаю ответ:

> user@devise:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade composer
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done composer is already the newest version
> (1.10.1-1). Calculating upgrade... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed,
> 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Как сделать апгрейд до Composer-2 ?
Инет очевидных ответов не дает.

Comment: что вам говорит `composer self-update` ?

Comment: @ArchDemon, насколько понимаю это годится для локальной установки. У меня глобальная. 

отвечает: 
> Command "self-update" is not defined.

Comment: А у меня пишет `A new stable major version of Composer is available (2.0.8), run "composer self-update --2" to update to it. See also https://github.com/composer/composer/releases for changelogs.` У вас какой-то неправильный composer и он делает неправильный мёд

Comment: @ArchDemon а у вас он локальный/глобальный?

Comment: Удалите свой и установите который все человеки устанавливают. Не из репозитория ОС, а скриптом с сайта